# protractor: test download file without knowing filename

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27031924/858913) and it looks almost the thing I need.

The problem there is that he already knows the filename and I am doing e2e test for downloading a file, but the filename depends on the current time (even with milliseconds) so I don't really know the name (or it would be very difficult to get it).

I think I am missing something very simple here, but I was thinking of two ways:

1. Recreate filenames (with the same function that returns the name of this file) and start checking for existance of a file with that name, if it doesn't exist, then move to the next millisecond until I hit the right name.
2. Check the download folder for existance of "any" file, if I find one there then it should be the file I am downloading (for this case I don't know how to check an entire folder in protractor).

Hope you guys could help with these alternatives (I would like some help with point 2) or maybe give me a better one. Thanks

Comment: Just the first thought came to my head: I'd probably clean up the download directory in the test set up and wait for any file (or file matching a specific glob pattern) - have not done that though, but maybe you can build something recursive using the `glob` package ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21320251/771848)) - search for the file until found, or the "timeout" happened - you can let jasmine control the timeout, or measure it manually yourself..thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I ended up following your suggestion, I just didn't know what to use for waiting, `setTimeout` or `browser.wait`

Comment: @alecxe it would be good if the browser itself would know about the browser it is downloading

Comment: @alecxe I am thinking on answering my own question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up following @alecxe's suggestion and here is my answer:

```
var glob = require("glob");

browser.driver.wait(function () {
    var filesArray = glob.sync(filePattern);
    if (typeof filesArray !== 'undefined' && filesArray.length > 0) {
        // this check is necessary because `glob.sync` can return
        // an empty list, which will be considered as a valid output
        // making the wait to end.
        return filesArray;
    }
}, timeout).then(function (filesArray) {
    var filename = filesArray[0];
    // now we have the filename and can do whatever we want
});
```

Comment: Note: I've cross-reposted it to the SQA site with some extra explanation: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/24439/5574.

Comment: @Nick it is a "glob" pattern like `*.xls` for example.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a little bit more background information to the @elRuLL's answer.

The main idea is based on 2 things:

- [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) fits the problem perfectly - it would *execute a function continuously until it evaluates to true or a timeout is reached*. And, the timeout mechanism is already built-in.
- [`glob` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) provides a way to look for filenames matching a certain pattern (in the worst case, you can wait for the `*.*` - basically, any file to appear)