# how to disable download popup for excel in firefox in Protractor

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, protractor

Using Protractor to run automation cases in Firefox and Chrome.

Chrome does not ask for popup by default but firefox does.So i had to add extra lines for FF.Below is the code. But it is not working. The file am downloading is an excel but i could see the content type as 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' in the dev window.Is that right? should i change it so something else?I tried [Download file on Firefox with protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526120/download-file-on-firefox-with-protractor) but it threw AssertionError: WebDriverError:
     Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'.So I'm using below approach to download to download folder which does not throw an error but still not working as expected

```
let profile = require('firefox-profile');        
let firefoxProfile = new profile();

// _browser = 'chrome';
_browser = 'firefox';


firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

exports.config = {
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
capabilities: {
    'browserName': _browser,
    'shardTestFiles': false,
    'maxInstances': 1,       
    'acceptInsecureCerts': true,
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        'args': ['--safe-mode'],
        'profile': firefoxProfile
    }
},
```

Comment: please try setting the Preferences `browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete=False` and `browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting=False`

Comment: I tried but same behaviour.firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
firefoxProfile.setPreference('browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete', false)
firefoxProfile.setPreference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', false)

Comment: I would be better if you update your question with this information, this isn't readable.

Comment: i tried your answer , but it is not working.By default the values for these 2 preferences are set to false.

Comment: I just tried firefoxProfile.setPreference('browser.download.dir', "C:\\QAAutomation");                When Save as popup came,i manually selected "save to" and then OK. It should get downloaded in C:\QAAautomation.But it is downloading in downloads folder. So I guess the profile is not yet linked to the automation browser.