# How to handle file download dialog box in protractor script for Firefox and IE browser

Tags: protractor

I have a requirement of downloading a excel file and PDF file in my project.But when i am trying to download a file, it showing a dialog box(asking to Open/Save the file) and it is not disappearing.How can i handle this in protractor script(I have only used the code for clicking on the download button).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file on Firefox with protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526120/download-file-on-firefox-with-protractor)

Comment: Also see https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/3169